# zenity input file with several lines

Tags: bash, input, line, cat, zenity

I have a problem with zenity I cannot work out. Could you guys help me?

I have a 7 line long tmp3 file:

```
AAA
BBB
...
FFF
GGG
```

I want to send this file through zenity so that it displays a checklist with the possibilty to check every line I want with every combination I want.

I previously wrote:

```
cat tmp3 | zenity --list \
                  --column='#' \
                  --text "Select playlist from the list below" \
                  --title "Please select one or more playlists" \
                  --multiple \
                  --width=300 \
                  --height=300 \
                  --checklist \
                  --column "Select" \
                  --separator="/ ")
```

All this does is create one single line in zenity with all 7 files of tmp3. Thats not what I want.

I currently wrote this:

```
choice=$(zenity --list \
                --column "Playlists" FALSE $(cat tmp3) \
                --text "Select playlist from the list below" \
                --title "Please select one or more playlists" \
                --multiple \
                --width=300 \
                --height=300 \
                --checklist \
                --column "Select" \
                --separator="/ ")
```

Here something really weird happens that I dont understand. 4 out of 7 fields are created in zenity: AAA CCC EEE and GGG. But not the other ones. When I set -x for debugging I can see all 7 lines being piped to zenity... What is happening?????

I tried another solution by listing the 7 subfolders in my current folder (which happen to have the exact same name as the lines in tmp3). The same thing happens!:

I wrote this:

```
choice=$(zenity --list \
                --column "Playlists" FALSE $(ls -d -1 */) \
                --text "Select playlist from the list below" \
                --title "Please select one or more playlists" \
                --multiple \
                --width=300 \
                --height=300 \
                --checklist \
                --column "Select" \
                --separator="/ ")
```

The second solution seems easier but my skills aren't very high. And I would like to understand the latter solution and why it does this.

Thank you guys!

EDIT:
I have found this and tried to make it work my way but no success so far... 
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/reading-lines-to-an-array-and-generate-dynamic-zenity-list-881421/

Answer (score 2):

The part `FALSE $(cat tmp3)` expands to

```
FALSE AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
GGG
```

What you need is

```
FALSE AAA
FALSE BBB
FALSE CCC
FALSE DDD
FALSE EEE
FALSE FFF
FALSE GGG
```

One way to achieve this is `--column "Playlists" $(sed s/^/FALSE\ / tmp3) \`

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting example in `man zenity` :

```
zenity \
    --list \
    --checklist \
    --column "Buy" \
    --column "Item" \
    TRUE Apples \
    TRUE Oranges \
    FALSE Pears \
    FALSE Toothpaste
```

You just need to turn on a neurone to adapt it a bit =)

[image: you can do it]

**EDIT**:

if you have an undefined length list, this example will be more interesting :

```
find . -name '*.h' |
zenity \
    --list \
    --title "Search Results" \
    --text "Finding all header files.." \
    --column "Files"
```

Comment: I already saw this and dont know how this relates to me. Yeah Im using a checklist but this example has a known number of colums. I dont. Thats why I want to pipe my tmp3 file to zenity

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use `--checkbox` and undefined list length at the same time !

Comment: Thank you for your new example, I got it working but I end up with the same problem that my example 2 and 3. Now I only have 3 lines in my zenity checklist: BBB CCC and DDD. I wrote this     `find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 | zenity --list \
                                --column "Playlists" \`

Comment: You need the files to be displayed each on a newline to pipe it to `zenity`. See `man ls`

Comment: I am sorry but dont think i understand what you mean. When do I need to use the ls tool? If you mean in tmp3, yes they are each on a different line (with no space at the end of each line if thats important). Could you be more clear please?

Comment: You don't need `ls` in particular but to display each item on a newline. You can use any command you want for that. How do you display the content of `tmp3` ? How it looks ?

Comment: Well easy its the way I wrote in the initial post. 7 lines with each a different name. If I `cat tmp3` alone in a terminal, I have 7 lines. I dont understand whats wrong

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm kinda late, but wanted just about the same thing, and figured it out in the end.
My solution does a search (hiding errors), adds TRUE and a newline to each result (that was the key!), then sends the result to zenity:

```
CHECKED=`find /music/folder -name "*.mp3" -type f 2>/dev/null | \
         awk '{print "TRUE\n"$0}' | \
         zenity --list --checklist --separator='\n' --title="Select Results." \
                --text="Finding all MP3 files..." --column="" --column="Files"`
```

In your situation, I guess this should be:

```
CHECKED=`cat tmp3 | awk '{print "TRUE\n"$0}' | zenity --list --checklist \
         --separator='/ ' --title="Select Results." \
         --text="Finding all MP3 files..." --column="" --column="Select"`
```

So it seems Zenity puts each newline in a column, and fills the list that way. This means you can manipulate the strings going into Zenity to add any number of colums.

Answer (score 0):

In short and clear summary, you have two options:

**Option one:**   Input file, newline separate the columns

Instead of

```
cat tmp3 | zenity ... ...
```

do:

```
sed 's/^/.\n/' tmp3 | zenity ... ...
```

**Option two:** Inline command, the colunms are read as pairs from the command args

Instead of

```
cat tmp3 | zenity ... ...
```

do:

```
zenity ... ... `sed 's/^/. /' tmp3`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ zenity --list --checklist --height 400 --text "Select playlist from the list below" --title "Please select one or more playlists" --column "Playlists" --column "Select" --separator="/ "  
$(ls -d -1 */ | xargs -L1 echo FALSE)
```